# how to count records of group by column

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a notifications table which stores userID,isRead,type,message

UserID is id of user.
isRead stores 1/0 for read/unread.
Type stores the kind of notification, "mention/follow/reply".
message is message which the user will see.

I need a group by query that can return distinct "type" and number of unread messages for that type, but limit count to 1 record only.

How do I change the query below to get a resultset like the below:

Please note, number of unread messages for that TYPE can be more, but I want the query to stop counting as soon as first record is found. Then it starts looking for other TYPEs.

Will it be faster to run 3 separate queries, one for each TYPE?

```
select type from table where userID=123 and isRead=0 group by type

0=array(
  'type'=> mention,
  'count'=> 1
)
1=array(
  'type'=> reply,
  'count'=> 1
)
and so on
```

Comment: Please add input data, and desired output based on that input data.  A description of `I need a group by query that can return distinct "type" and number of unread messages for that type, but limit count to 1 record only` is pretty useless for someone who is not natively speaking English (like me) 

Comment: "Will it be faster to run 3 separate queries, one for each TYPE?" Try, and check.... You do have some data, the readers he do not have data...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like:

```
select type 
from mytable 
where userID = 123 
group by type
having min(isRead) = 0
```

The query filters on the given user, groups by type, and selects only groups where at least one row is unread.

For performance, the following index *may* help:

```
mytable(userID, type, isRead)
```

Comment: Hi, this is working, but I think it is still reading entire table from top to bottom. Is there a way to stop reading the table if all three types are found? Then it can stop reading and return the resultset. Thanks

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, where you can’t really specify such requirement. For performance, instead, consider creating the index I suggested in my answer, which should speed up the query @John.

Comment: Hi, those indexes are already there, in same order as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help

```
SELECT type FROM (
    SELECT type FROM table WHERE type = 'mention' AND userID = 123 AND isRead = 0 LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT type FROM table WHERE type = 'follow' AND userID = 123 AND isRead = 0 LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT type FROM table WHERE type = 'reply' AND userID = 123 AND isRead = 0 LIMIT 1
) AS X
```

Comment: Isn't that same as reading the entire table three times? That is what I want to avoid, reading a large table multiple times.

Comment: Yes it is. It satisfies your demand to skip scanning further once a match is found, and should be the fastest if you have the proper index in place.